# Comparing 2 files with the same content and being told that they are different

Tags: c#, file-properties

I'm using the following method to compare 2 files:

```
static bool comparatabelas(string path1, string path2)
    {
        byte[] file1 = File.ReadAllBytes(path1);
        byte[] file2 = File.ReadAllBytes(path2);
        if (file1.Length == file2.Length) //só verifica comprimento
        {
            //comando for adicionado ao original, com este dava sempre falso
            for (int i = 0; i < file1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (file1[i] != file2[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comparing the files by iterating over every character in each of them works, and I have tried it several times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < file1.Length; i++)
{
    if (file1[i] != file2[i])
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

However, if I use this particular piece of code it will give the result that the files are different even though they have the exact same content. I even tried to save the 2nd file in another folder but with the same name; however, I still got the result that they were different. Any advice on how I can fix this problem?

UPDATE:

I was saving tabledata's via xmlwrite, happens that when i was comparing, they had different table names, never tought it could be that, nevermind.

Comment: When it returns false, what are the runtime values of `file1[i]` and `file2[i]`?  How have you confirmed that the files are *exactly* the same?

Comment: What if you put breakpoint on `return false;` and see the exact values instead of guessing?

Comment: obviously they are not the same.Also you can just use `SequenceEqual` instead of for loop.

Comment: @David: doesn't `==` overload use `.Equals()` for strings?

Comment: @zerkms: It indeed might, that wouldn't surprise me.  But having more granular control over the comparison options could be of use.  I just noticed, however, that these are byte arrays instead of strings, so it's kind of moot in this case anyway.

Comment: put a breakpoint on `return false` and see what it shows.

Comment: @zerkms i've just tried that, and they seem exactly the same

Comment: @César Amorim: so you're stating that C# returns `true` for `!=` comparison of 2 *equal* `byte`s?

Comment: If `file1.Length < file2.Length`, then the character-by-character version will falsely report the files as equal.